# How return a message from servlet without leave jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp, servlets

i have a doubt, this is my scenario, when an user (in register.jsp) click in 'register' would like to go to my servlet and do all the stuff that have to be done. And i would like to return a message in the same register.jsp that tells if the register was sucessful or not, i don't want to redirect to another .jsp.

Is this   possible ?

I  developed a box that appears in the register checking if the data that the user provide are valid, is in javascript + css, i would like to use this box, if possible.

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use ajax, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> ```
> $.ajax({
>   url: "check.jsp",
>   context: document.body,
>   success: function(){
>      // do something when you got the message.
>   }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). You can do it with [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) easily.

Comment: @ata there are many framework our, but DWR can be easily plugged into simple web-app.